# Ошибка NU3018 в Linux Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, nuget

ОС Linux Red OS, Visual Studio Code. Создал начальный проект Avalonia. И с самого начала появились проблемы:

> /home/alvahtin/VisualStudio/GetStartedApp/GetStartedApp.csproj : error NU3018: Package 'System.Linq 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's signing certificate is not trusted by the trust provider.

Я так понял, что проблема с сертификатами nuget, и эта проблема только в Linux но как это лечить?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3018
To opt out, set the environment variable DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION to false

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл как это лечится. Как сделать догадался прочитав эту [статью](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7688), где я взял ссылку на [сертификат](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/src/Layout/redist/trustedroots/codesignctl.pem) и скачал его. Как устанавливать автоматически не знаю, поэтому сделал всё вручную: скопировал его в `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` предварительно изменив ему расширение на crt (может, это и не нужно). И запустил команду `update-ca-trust` и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

> Нашёл как это лечится. Как сделать догадался прочитав эту статью, где я взял ссылку на сертификат и скачал его. Как устанавливать автоматически не знаю, поэтому сделал всё вручную: скопировал его в /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors предварительно изменив ему расширение на crt (может, это и не нужно). И запустил команду update-ca-trust и всё заработало.

Спасибо. Установка этих сертификатов помогла избавиться от аналогичной ошибки при сборке Unreal Engine 5.3.2 на Alt Linux

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/911238)